# Why can I bind a function taking by-value argument to a std::function taking a lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

After digging to find the source of a bug, I was surprised to discover that the following seems to be legal C++11 (compiles fine with GCC/clang with Wall). In particular, why can I assign `f1`, which takes its argument by value to a `RefFunction` which expects an argument by reference ?

I tried googling for an explanation, but didn't find anything relevant, probably because I don't know exactly what to google for. I'd really appreciate if someone can guide me through why this is legal.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1(int val) {
  val = 1;
}

void f2(int& val) {
  val = 2;
}

using RefFunction = std::function<void(int&)>;

int main()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  int val = 42;
  // I was expecting a compile error here telling me that f1 doesn't 
  // have the right signature (int instead of int&)
  RefFunction f = f1;
  f(val);
  cout << val << endl;  // prints 42

  // This makes sense, f2 takes argument by reference
  f = f2;
  f(val);
  cout << val << endl;  // prints 2
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting aside the standardese for the time being, think in terms of the following:

```
void f1(int val) {
  val = 1;
}

void f2(int& val) {
  val = 2;
}

void WrapperFunction(int& val)
{
   f1(val); // Should be OK
   f2(val); // Should be OK.
}
```

The compiler should not have any problems with the above code. If you think of `WrapperFunction` analogous to a `std::function`, the compiler should not have any problem regardless of whether the `std::function` is constructed with `f1` or `f2`.

Answer (score 4):

The template argument of `std::function` enforces the manner in which the `std::function` may be called; therefore a `RefFunction` can only be called with an lvalue of type `int` or something that can be implicitly converted to an lvalue of type `int`. It will then call the underlying function, `f1` or `f2`. A function that receives a reference to `int` can always use that reference to call a function that takes `int` by value; the `int` referred to will simply be copied.

In general `std::function<R(T...)>` can store a callable with any signature as long as it's true that the `T...` parameters of the `std::function`'s function call operator can actually be used to call the underlying callable. The signatures don't need to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This actually make sense now. I can unfortunately only accept one answer and I'd say both answers are good.